Firebase Multicast Message Integration Connection Max pool warning
I am encountering an issue with Firebase where I see the following error message in the logs:
Firebase Connection pool is full, discarding connection: oauth2.googleapis.com. Connection pool size: 10
This error seems to be related to the connection pool being full, with a default pool size of 10. However, I’m not sure why the connections are getting discarded and if there's a way to fix this.
Here are some details about my setup:
Firebase version: 6.6.0
The method causing the issue: send_for_each_multicast
tokens: 500
I've already tried increasing the connection pool size in the configuration, but the error persists. Does anyone know how to resolve this or what could be causing the connection pool to be overwhelmed?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance!
When i send 10 tokens less, it does not give an warning, but when i send more than 10, it gives this warning.
Firebase Connection pool is full, discarding connection: oauth2.googleapis.com. Connection pool size: 10
